# Device node in /dev for a smart card reader

Tags: shell-script, smartcard

I'm looking for a method to determine the device nodes (under `/dev` hierarchy) of all smart card readers in the system. Additionally, I need to run this method from a shell script.

The `pcsc_scan` tool obviously knows how to find these device nodes, but I can't find any useful information in its output.

**Motivation**: I've built a Dockerfile that containerizes an application that accesses smart card readers. Everything works fine, but I'm using the `--privileged` and `--volume` options with the `/dev` path, instead of a specific `--device` option. I do this because I'm unable to determine the specific device node associated to the smart card reader. This is a security concern since I'm giving too much visibility to the container over the system devices.